# How to Configure a Multi-value Parameter in SSRS to also not pass any values

Tags: variables, reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008

I am trying to create a parameter that filters on a certain field, but to also not work (for lack of a better term or be blank/NULL) if the user does not want to select a filter.
The SSRS report shows the summary of an event. Some events have equipment assigned to the event, while others do not.
If I do not create the equipment parameter, the report will show me all records: with equipment or without. In the example below, events (Drive ID) 683708, 683634, 683646) do not have an incentive assigned so the field is null.  Which is good.

[image: No Equipment Parameter]

But when I add a parameter for Equipment, I am forced to make a selection and events with no equipment assigned are no longer displayed. I know why this is happening and it makes sense, but I am hoping there is a way to make the Equipment parameter allow me to select ‘None’ or ‘Blank’ or whatever the wording may be to see all of the drives in the date range.

[image: Equipment Parameter]

My procedure looks like this:

```
Create Procedure Hemasphere_IncentiveReport
@startDate datetime,
@endDate datetime,
@RegID varchar(8000),
@OrgID varchar(8000),
@SubID varchar(8000),
@COID varchar(8000),
@EquipmentID varchar(8000)

As

Begin

Select
DM.DriveID [DriveID],
DM.FromDateTime [FromDateTime],
Case When DM.OwnerType = 0 Then Acct.Name Else CD.DescLong End As [OwnerName],
CO.CodeID [CO_ID],
CO.Description [CO_Desc],
Org.CodeID [Org_ID],
Org.Description [Org_Desc],
Sub.CodeID [Sub_ID],
Sub.Description [Sub_Desc],
Reg.CodeID [Reg_ID],
Reg.Description [Reg_Desc],
Inc.Description [Incentive]

From
Hemasphere_Dev.[dbo].rpt_DriveMaster DM
Left Outer Join Hemasphere_Dev.[dbo].rpt_Accounts Acct on DM.AccountID=Acct.AccountID
Inner Join Hemasphere_Dev.[dbo].rpt_CenterDetail CD on DM.CenterID=CD.CenterID
Inner Join Hemasphere_Dev.[dbo].IDViewCollectionOp CO on CD.CenterID=CO.CodeID
Inner Join Hemasphere_Dev.[dbo].IDViewRegion Reg on CD.Region=Reg.CodeID
Inner Join Hemasphere_Dev.[dbo].IDViewOrgCenter Org on CD.OrgCenter=Org.CodeID
Inner Join Hemasphere_Dev.[dbo].IDViewOrgSubCenter Sub on CD.OrgSubCenter=Sub.CodeID
Left Outer Join OBAPPS.[dbo].OBI_Incentives Inc on DM.DriveID=Inc.DriveID

Where
DM.StatusID <>5
And DM.FromDateTime Between @startDate AND @endDate
And CO.CodeID In (Select Number From dbo.fn_SplitInt(@COID,','))
And Inc.EquipmentID In (Select Number from dbo.fn_SplitInt(@EquipmentID,','))

Order By [FromDateTime], [OwnerName], [CO_Desc], [Rec_Desc]
```

I have tried a solution like:

```
And (Inc.EquipmentID IS NULL or Inc.EquipmentID In (Select Number from dbo.fn_SplitInt(@EquipmentID,',')))
```

But that gives me null values back when I select specific equipment.  Any suggestions on what I could do to accomplish this task?

Thanks Alan, feel like it's almost there and hoping you might be able to help me clear this final hurdle.  If I change my parameter, I get this error:

[image: Parameter Error]

And for the procedure itself, you say to use:

```
AND (Inc.EquipmentID IN (@EquipmentID) OR (-1 IN (@EquipmentID) AND Inc.EquipmentID IS NULL))
```

But wouldn't I need to call the function to split the integers as well:

```
And (Inc.EquipmentID In (Select Number From dbo.fnSplitInt(@EquipmentID,',') Or (-1 IN (@EquipmentID) AND Inc.EquipmentID IS NULL))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the dataset for your Equipment parameter, manually add a blank value first.

For example:

```
Select -1 as Value, 'No Equipment' as Label
UNION ALL
```

Select your original Equipment dataset here

Then in your report query, instead of this:

```
And (Inc.EquipmentID IS NULL or Inc.EquipmentID In (Select Number from dbo.fn_SplitInt(@EquipmentID,',')))
```

Do this:

```
AND (Inc.EquipmentID IN (@EquipmentID)
OR (-1 IN (@EquipmentID) AND Inc.EquipmentID IS NULL))
```

Comment: Thanks Alan, feel like it's almost there.  I edited my question in hopes you can help me get this resolved.

Comment: In a union, the columns will take the name of the first record inserted, so in your ORDER BY the column "Description" no longer exists since it's now called "Label". Change the column names of the blank value (Value, Label) to match the names of your dataset (EquipmentID, Description).

Comment: SSRS should handle the splitting automatically, so try it without splitting the integers first.

Comment: SSRS will split when inserting into a stored procedure?

Comment: Oh no sorry I missed that part. It would if you had that query as your dataset instead of having it in a stored procedure though.

Comment: Thanks, this worked so well I quit trying to use a stored procedure and going with an embedded query.